# Add entry to newly created crontab using shell scripting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to add an entry like `*/15  *  *  *  * php -f /var/www/cron.php` to a newly created crontab using shell scripting in Ubuntu 14.04.

The purpose of this is to automatically provision a vagrant machine.

If i run `sudo crontab -u http -e` it will give me a UI asking for an editor which i don't want as it will complicate things since i would first have to save the file and so on.

I just want the easiest way to create crontabs using shell scripting

Comment: Crossposting: http://askubuntu.com/q/704571/336375

Comment: Why make one's life easier when it is so much more fun to make it more complex?

Answer (score 1):

The "simple" solution is very simple, but also risky.

```
crontab <<':'
*/15  *  *  *  * php -f /var/www/cron.php
:
```

This will **replace any existing crontab.**

A somewhat less risky approach is to check for an existing crontab, and add the desired stanza at the end if it is missing; but you can't really avoid a race condition.

The sanest solution is probably to have a modular `crontab` designed around `run-parts` or something similar; but this is unfortunately not a standard feature.

Comment: Nice! I also like this approach: [How can I programmatically create a new cron job?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13355743/1983854) --> `(crontab -l ; echo "0 * * * * your_command") | sort - | uniq - | crontab -`.